# Ms Access, ADODB, Recordset, Set Primarykey

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, adodb

I scussefully connect an ADODB.Recordset with a PostgreSQL Table:

```
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Source = psql
rs.LockType = adLockPessimistic
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rs.index = "id"
rs.Open
```

I can update data:

```
rs!somefield = "somevalue"
rs.update
```

I can add data:

```
rs.AddNew
rs!someRequiredFiled = "somevalue"
rs.update
```

But updating data is not working, if the data is changed in background:

```
rs!somefield = "somevalue"
// .... the same field was changed for an other user
rs.update
// -> Error, cause the field to be changed is not found anymore
```

I think the Problem is, that the Recordset is not informed about the primary key. Right? And how can I set the Primary key?

Comment: You need to provide more specifics. Are you using a server-side or a client-side cursor? (`Debug.Print con.CursorLocation`). Is the primary key for the record being changed? (That's a major bad practice, primary keys are not meant to be changed)

Comment: The CursorLocation is 2 for the Connection and Recordsetl. The index is empty if not set manually to the pk.

Comment: I add one line of code to set the cursorLocation for the Recordset to Client and updating works very well. Also a second problem is solved: Updating in a connected Form no works to - including a popup Dialog on conflicts. But I see it doesnt matter if I sel the rs.index property or let it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a client-side cursor, the record generally is identified by its primary key, or, if that's not present, the record isn't updateable.

When using a server-side cursor, the server keeps track of which record you're working on, and it can be identified by things like a primary key or a rowversion indicator. If the server is tracking a specific row version, and that row gets changed, it will lose track of it if it's not notified.

Use `Connection.CursorLocation = adUseClient` to use a client-side cursor.

The `Recordset.Index` property is used for something else entirely. It's used for executing `Recordset.Seek` commands for recordsets opened with `CommandType = adCmdTableDirect` and using a server-side cursor. If you print `Recordset.Supports(adIndex)`, you will note your recordset doesn't support it after opening. Setting an unsupported property can either raise an error or just do nothing in ADO.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination and pointing me in the right direction. It is up to me, to dive deeper into the concept of database cursors.